# How to fix boto3 aws botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError:

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from crocolinks.models import CrocoLink
from datetime import datetime
import os
import shutil
import boto3
import logging
from botocore.config import Config
import requests
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError, NoCredentialsError
import time
from twisted.internet import task, reactor
##mysqlimport
#import mysql.connector
from pathlib import Path
from os import path
###AWS INFO####

# print(list_objects_bucket)


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Linkebis aploadi'

    def handle(self,*args,**kwargs):
        access_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        access_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        bucket_name = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        bucket_name2= 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        client = boto3.client('s3')
        list_objects_bucket = client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name)

        # mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="newuser",database="cointrack",passwd="password")
        # mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        ####Connet To S3 Service
        client_s3= boto3.client(
            
            's3',
            region_name="eu-west-2",
            aws_access_key_id=access_key,
            aws_secret_access_key=access_secret
        )

        counter = 0
        s3_resource = boto3.resource("s3", region_name="eu-west-2")
        #upload files to S3 Bucker
        data_file_folder = r"//10.0.83.27/Shared/123"
        t1 = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
         
        try:
            #bucket_name = "S3_Bucket_Name" #s3 bucket name
            data_file_folder = r"//10.0.83.27/Shared/123/" # local folder for upload

            my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
            my_bucket2= s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name2)

            for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(data_file_folder):
                path = path.replace("\\","/")
                directory_name = path.replace(data_file_folder,"")
                Destination_dir= "//10.0.83.27/Shared/gadatanilebi/"
                Dest_dir_xelmeored="//10.0.83.277/Shared/Xelmeoredatvirtulebi/"
                for file in files:
                    if os.path.isfile(Destination_dir+file)==False:
                
                        
                        now = datetime.now()
                        my_bucket2.upload_file(os.path.join(path, file),file)
                        t1 = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                        print('Uploading file {0}...'.format(file))
                        print(path)
                        print(t1)
                        
                        counter+=1
                        #shutil.move(path+"/"+file, Destination_dir)
                        print(file)
                        shutil.move((path+"/"+file), os.path.join(Destination_dir,file))
                    else:
                        if os.path.isfile(Destination_dir+file)==True: #### Tu ukve ertxel gadatanili iqneb sxva foldershi gadaitans ro ar gadaawero
                            now = datetime.now()
                            my_bucket.upload_file(os.path.join(path, file),file)#directory_name+'/'+file)  ###bucketze Uploadi
                            my_bucket2.upload_file(os.path.join(path, file),file)
                            t1 = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                            print('Uploading file {0}...'.format(file))
                            print(path)
                            print(t1)
                            
                            #shutil.move(path+"/"+file, Destination_dir)
                            print(file)
                            counter+=1
                            shutil.move((path+"/"+file), os.path.join(Dest_dir_xelmeored,file))
            print(counter)


                        #shutil.copytree(path+"/"+file, Destination_dir, file_exist_ok=True) 

                        

                            # os.rename(file,Destination_dir)
```

When i try to run into my local computer work correctly , but when i move into `Windows server 2021` 
THere is error code

```
  File "C:\Users\loc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\botocore\auth.py", line 357, in add_auth
    raise NoCredentialsError
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

What is problem ? Credentials is 100% correct , because as I told it's work in my local computer.
I mean , when i run in my Computer , Windows 10 it's works correctly , when i run another computer , Windows 2012 server not works

Comment: You are creating two s3 client objects, one with credentials and one without. Then you proceed to use the one without credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you provided credentials in code, you are not using it anywhere.

It works in your local machine because, you might have AWS CLI installed and configured credentials and the code would have used that configured creds

The below code will use inline creds in code, however would advice you to use creds set using EC2 instance profile deployed to AWS or use configured creds with CLI

```
import boto3
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=access_secret
)

 s3_resource = session.resource("s3", region_name="eu-west-2")
```

Comment: What it means? " Though you provided credentials in code, you are not using it anywhere" , how to fix or use correctly?

Comment: See the usage of "session" and "s3_resource" variable and compare with with your code, you will get the answer